# What can affect the rewards in Spy Missions?

Tags: warframe

I 've been doing my best to try and farm for Ivara in Warframe, and I have checked and cross-checked my info, but I simply do not appear to be getting the Neuroptics.

I have checked and cross-checked my info, and I should be getting the Neuroptics from the mission I'm farming, which is Rosalind on Uranus. However lately, I've noticed that not only am I not getting the base Blueprint at all (I got 2 of them when I first started), I'm occasionally only getting 2 drops, instead of 3.

The [drop tables](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Rosalind#Mission_Rewards) say that I can get a Mod, Endo or Credits on Tier 1, a Relic on Tier 2, And a Mod, Ivara Blueprint, or Ivara Neuroptics Blueprint on Tier 3.

There were times I was getting a Mod and a Relic, there were times I was getting 2 Mods and a Relic. I did manage to get three Ivara Blueprints, but after a while I stopped getting those as well, and *never* the Neuroptics.

Is there anything that can affect the possibility of not getting the Tier 3 reward? Such as triggering the alarm, or using a Cypher, or aggroing the enemy (without triggering the alarm), but still successfully hacking the panel, or is the only thing that stops you from getting the Tier 3 reward not successfully hacking the panel?

Comment: Ivara parts drop on rotation C only, which means you can only get it by successfully hacking all vaults(I recently farmed it myself, and that was the case then).

Comment: @Daedalus yeah, I'm aware of that. The question however is about what can affect the "successful" hacking. E.g. does triggering the alarms affect it? Does using a Cypher? Anything else?

Comment: Not that I know of; just the vaults being all successfully opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been playing Warframe since 2013. I'm not saying that my word is always right, but this time I am 100% sure that, you're just unlucky.

Nothing affects the rewards if you're playing correct mission. Spotted by enemies? no. Using Cypher? no (in fact, I always use Cypher if I can; Cypher couldn't be used at some circumstances, such as Sortie). You just need to open 3 vaults, nothing more is required. I have actually farmed Ivara's system for like 3 weeks to finally get the blueprint. I was so unlucky at that moment, but still I got them. You just need to play more.

Even if you got spotted 2 or 3 times, the mission just adds Extermination aspect (Lotus wants you to kill enemies like Extermination mission), but rewards (as in item) won't change. The only reward change is that how many XP you will get; you won't get undetected hacking bonus. That's all.

Comment: Yup, after a few more days I completely botched all 3 (thought still retrieved the data) and managed to get another blueprint. The frustrating thing about chance is that it is no guarantee haha

Comment: @Ben The infamous desire sensor is real :p Good luck on your journey, Tenno!